# Nested Loop scenario, getting values before exception in debug mode - Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

If I have a nested loop scenario and I am stepping into it in debug mode. Ex:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listTest.Count; i++)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < anotherList.Count; j++)
   {
      //Some logic that throws an exception
   }
}
```

Is there a way for me to know the values of `i, j, listTest[i] and anotherLIst[j]` just before the exception occurred? If the count values are high, it's impractical to loop through the loops and watch these values before the exception occurs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you could change the settings in VS2008 to break on exception when thrown:

```
Debug >> Exception >> Common Language Runtime Exceptions Dialog
```

This will cause the debugger to stop on the line of code that generates the offending exception, and `i` and `j` should be in scope at that point.

You could also promote the loop variables i and j outside of the loops;  like so:

```
int i, j;
for (i = 0; i < listTest.Count; i++)
{
   for (j = 0; j < anotherList.Count; j++)
   {
      //Some logic that throws an exception
   }
}
```

Comment: One of the hidden gems of VS.

Answer (score 1):

Surround all the code inside the second loop with a try/catch block.  Catch the exception and rethrow it.  Place your breakpoint on the line within the catch.  When the exception occurs, i and j should be the value at the time of the exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup Visual Studio to break for all exceptions. In Visual Studio goto Debug->Exceptions in the menu. The check to break when an exception is thrown for Common Language Runtime Exceptions. This will cause it to break here without a catch.

Note: You probably don't want this on all the time, and if you are using logic that could possible throw an exception you should be using a try/catch.